# VirtualBox bridged adapter can ping but can't curl

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ping, bridge

There is a dedicated server running Ubuntu Server 12.04.2. There are 4 useable IPs for this server: A, B, C, D. The server itself takes A.

The server is now running two VirtualBox guests, both with "Bridged adapter" network type. One guest is running Windows Server 2003, using IP address B. Another one is running Arch Linux (Live CD), using IP address C.

1. In the Ubuntu host, the network is fine. I can `apt-get` and the downloading speed is good.
2. In Windows guest, I can `ping www.google.com` in cmd.exe, but I cannot visit www.google.com in IE6.
3. In Arch Linux guest, I can `ping www.google.com` in zsh, but `curl -v www.google.com` does not work. I can also `telnet www.google.com 80`, which means at least 80/tcp and 53/udp ports are working. (There is no iptables firewall on the server, actually.)
4. In Arch Linux guest, I can even `ssh` to another machine! (using standard 22/tcp )
5. In Arch Linux guest, I try to `wget` some https site, it stuck at "Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443... connected".

I've tried changing `--nictype1` setting for the VM and/or setting different MTUs in the guest OS, but the problem continues.

Can anyone help me?

Addtional information: When changing "Bridged adapter" to "NAT", the guest OS can `curl www.google.com`. Everything is fine. But since I need public IP, I have to use "Bridged adapter" for guest OS.

Addtional informationi 2: In guest OS with "Bridged adapter", I can `ssh` other host using 22/tcp, I can `dig` some domain using 53/udp, but I cannot `wget` or `curl` websites using 80/tcp or 443/tcp, but `telnet www.google.com 80` or `telnet www.google.com 443` is fine. When using "NAT" , everything is fine.

Comment: Are you behind a transparent proxy or something like this ?

Comment: @Bertera No, I figured out why... See my own answer below.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is not a production environment, so I do not think there is anything wrong with VirtualBox...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I figured out this by myself.

I by accident found that I can `curl google.com` but cannot `curl www.google.com` and since the first one is rather smaller, I think this is a problem with MTU or something, causing the guest OS being unable to transfer large segment of data.

After googling "virtual bridged mtu" I found this post: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=30632&start=0

Then I tried `ethtool -K eth2 sg off rx off tx off tso off` in the Ubuntu Server (eth2 is the bridged interface), and... it works like a charm! Instantly

Comment: Wow, I would not have made the connection to the MTU being the problem. Good thinking!

Comment: Of the 4 settings that tries to change, two are successful, but the other two return errors for: `Cannot change scatter-gather` and `Cannot change tcp-segmentation-offload`.  So the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.

the default MTU of bridged nic in vm is 1500. but when I use the ping with DF flag to detect the actual MTU, it turn out to be the 1498.

So, this problem could be solved by typing `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1498` in my host.